# Copying and pasting rows with certain text from selected workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am completely new to VBA so I don't know how to code much. I want to be able to select which file to copy and paste into my workbook. I have written the first part of my code:

```
Sub BCR_2019()
Dim FileToOpen As Variant
Dim Openbook As Workbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select one file", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*xls*")
If FileToOpen <> False Then
    Set Openbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
    Openbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:E20").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Paste
    Openbook.Close False
    
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Right now it only does a simple copy and paste of A1:E20. But I want the macro to copy and paste only the rows where the SOW includes "tq", the data looks like this:

[image]

I just don't know where to put the rest of the code or how to code this part.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take this opportunity to learn VBA: Nothing help one learn more than an exciting project. I suggest you record a macro with all the steps you need, then study and play with the generated code. I suspect you have 90% chance of getting this to work, but if you have problems, you can then come back with some code that you worked on and people can help you. As a suggestion, you can autofilter the column by going to "Text Filters" -> "Contains" and type "tq", copy the filtered range and past it into the destination and see what the macro recorder generates. All the best

Comment: You have to change code starting at the line where you copy `Range("A1:E20")`.  Either use `Find` or `AutoFilter` on the second column for `*tq`;   If using Find you will have to use a `Loop` through the column and copy each row that has `*tq`.       
If using `AutoFilter`, filter for "*tg" then select the range and use `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` to copy/paste the visible data to `("Sheet1").Range("C2")`

Comment: Hey @SuperSymmetry thanks for the advice. The problem I have with macro rec is that it locks on these cells. I want it so that whenever I have new data, it will be able to apply this rule still. When I use the macro recorder, it says this, which I am trying to avoid:

`Rows("1:1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Range("E4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$D$8").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array("btq", _
        "ctq", "ftq"), Operator:=xlFilterValues`

I am trying to avoid it selecting btq, ctq, and ftq permantently

Comment: Thank you so much @GMalc I will try this out

Comment: There are plenty of examples on SO and Google, just do a search for `Find partial value in column` or `AutoFilter Copy Visible`

Comment: @maronce Fantastic! Thank you for trying the macro recorder. When you come back with the code you mentioned, we can advise you to change `Criteria1:=Array(...)` to `Criteria1:="*tq*"` (not the `*`s and that should work for you. Try it out. The macro recorder is a fantastic tool. It gives you a starting point and then you can adapt the generated code to make it more dynamic.

Comment: You can google "wildcard characters in excel and vba" to understand what the astrisks do. `"*tq*"` simply means a string that has any sequence of any characters followed by "tq" followed by any sequence of any characters, which means any text that contains "tq".

Comment: In my comment above I meant to say (**note** the `*`

Answer (score 0):

Combining code from your question and your comments, you can do something like this
(Not tested but if there's any problem, please comment below)

```
Sub BCR_2019()
    Dim FileToOpen As Variant
    Dim Openbook As Workbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select one file", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*xls*")
    If FileToOpen <> False Then
        Set Openbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
        With Openbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:E20")
            .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="*tq*" ' or if always ends with tq then use "*tq"
            .Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2")
            Openbook.Close False
            
            ' Now you can do some cleaning
            ' Remove the added autofilter
            .AutoFilter
            ' Stop the "copy" flickering border
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End With
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Hope this helps